# How do I use FileBeat to send log data in pipe separated format to Elasticsearch in JSON format?

Tags: elasticsearch, logstash, kibana, elastic-stack, filebeat

The log file that I am monitoring has logs in the following format:

```
Oct 23 16:06:44 server smbd_audit: user01|192.168.0.23|project|opendir|ok|.
Oct 23 16:06:44 server smbd_audit: user01|192.168.0.23|project|closedir|ok|
Oct 23 16:06:44 server smbd_audit: user01|192.168.0.23|project|open|ok|r|file.txt
Oct 23 16:06:44 server smbd_audit: user01|192.168.0.23|project|pread|ok|file.txt
Oct 23 16:06:44 server smbd_audit: user01|192.168.0.23|project|close|ok|file.txt
```

How can I format this data before sending it to Elasticsearch using FileBeat?

I want my document to look like the following (excluding the elasticsearch metadata fields):

```
{
  "timestamp": "Oct 23 16:06:44",
  "machine-name": "server",
  "type": "smbd_audit",
  "username": "user01",
  "machine-ip": "192.168.0.23",
  "directory": "project",
  "operation": "opendir",
  "success": "ok",
  "file": "file.txt"
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume you don't want to use Logstash, so you could probably use an [ingest pipeline](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/master/ingest.html) with [Grok](https://github.com/logstash-plugins/logstash-patterns-core/blob/master/patterns/grok-patterns).

```
put _ingest/my-pipeline    
{
  "description": "My Ingest Pipeline",
  "processors": [
    {
      "grok": {
        "field": "message",
        "patterns": [
          "%{SYSLOGTIMESTAMP:log_date} %{WORD:machine-name} %{WORD:type}: %{WORD:username}|{IP:machine-ip}|{WORD:directory}|{WORD:operation}|{WORD:success}|{WORD:file}"
        ]
      }
    },
    {
      "date": {
        "field": "log_date"
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

Totally untested, but should at least give you something to go on.

Comment: Thank you @dwjv for introducing ingest pipeline to me.

Comment: No problem, FYI, the "date" section at the bottom is so that you can use the date/time in the log to search on (in Kibana etc.), rather than the default ingestion date. Was untested, you may need to add a format so that ES can translate it properly. e.g `"date":{"field":"log_date","formats": ["MMM dd HH:mm:ss"]}`